# Delegater NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, delegates

I created a Rest Webservice with ASP.NET MVC 4 and in my Webservice I'm calling a delegater which is called MessageInformer.

```
public MessageRepository repository = new MessageRepository();

public HttpResponseMessage PostMessage([FromBody]CoreMessage item)
{
    bool status = repository.TransmitMessage(item);
    if (status == true)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse<bool>(HttpStatusCode.OK, status);
    }
    else
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse<bool>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, status);
    }

}

public class MessageRepository : IMessageRepository
{
    public static MessageInformer Informer;

    public void SetDelegater(MessageInformer i)
    {
        Informer = i;
    }

    public bool TransmitMessage(CoreMessage item)
    {
        Informer(item);

        return true;
    }
}
```

When I start running the program I set a value to the delegater

```
 MessageRepository mr = new MessageRepository();
    mr.SetDelegater(informer);
```

that it should call the function New_MessageReceived and in the debug mode I see that the delegater has the right value after declaring it but when I call the Rest client after starting the program and it's comming to the function TransmitMessage(CoreMessage item) the delegater Informer is null although I assigned a value to it before. I set some breakpoints and it's never entering the function or the delegater between the starting and the web request so I don't have any idea why my delegater is null.

Rest client

```
try
{
    url = "http://localhost:5089/api/message";
    method = "POST";
    string messageString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = method;
    request.ContentType = "application/json; chatset=utf-8";

    using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        writer.Write(messageString);
    }

    var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

    if (request.HaveResponse == true && response == null)
    {
        String msg = "response was not returned or is null";
        throw new WebException(msg);
    }
    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        String msg = "response with status: " + response.StatusCode + " " + response.StatusDescription;
        throw new WebException(msg);
    }

    // check response headers for the content type
    string contentType = response.GetResponseHeader("Content-Type");

    // get the response content
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
    string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();

    Console.WriteLine("Received " + messageString);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    reponseAsString += "ERROR: " + ex.Message;
}
```

Comment: I can see the initialization : public MessageRepository repository = new MessageRepository(); , is calling the default constructor rather than the one with 'MessageInformer' as parameter. What if you modify the code to something like: public MessageRepository repository = new MessageRepository(new MessageInformer()); ?

Answer (score 0):

this

```
public MessageRepository repository = new MessageRepository();
```

not that

```
MessageRepository mr = new MessageRepository();
mr.SetDelegater(informer);
```

You should make sure repository is initialized properly (did you forget to assign **mr** to **<object>.repository**?).

Comment: I initialized it before but unfortunately it's the same issue...by starting the program the delegater gets the right value but when I call my rest client after starting the program the delegater's value is null